# Image with Embedded Links

Tags: 2013, javascript, 2016, 2019, visio

I have a image.  In the image I have boxes that if a user clicks it would open another page.  In SharePoint 2013 I could use a visio diagram and link the box to the other pages in the image.  How can I have a image and add links inside the image in SharePoint 2019? Microsoft removed Visio web part in SharePoint 2019.  Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an image map for this and display it using a script web part.
Here is a good generator: https://www.image-map.net/ where you can define the links and clickable areas and then copy the finished code.

In the resulting code you would have to update the image source to where you actually have uploaded the image, so for example

```
<img src="sample.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
```

would be changed to:

```
<img src="/sites/somesite/SiteAssets/sample.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
```